# Plannarity testing of a graph in c#

Tags: c#, boost, graph

I have a graph which i wish to test for plannarity. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/boyer_myrvold.html) does have an implementation but as i need to use it in c# i cant use boost, because it is written in c++ even [LEDA](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_guide/graph_algorithms/planar_kuratowski.html) same problem . Are there any such libraries for c#? I wish to find a suitable library as i dont have the time to implement such algorithms found in the papers referenced in the reference section of [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing).

Comment: Good question! I did a Google search on "Boyer-Myrvold Planarity Testing" ... and, to my surprise, came up empty handed.  This link has some good pointers ... but nothing specific for C#/.Net: [How to check if a graph is planar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854711/how-to-check-if-a-graph-is-a-planar-graph-or-not).  SUGGESTION: Perhaps you can use the Boost library, and call it (e.g. PInvoke()) from your C# program?

Comment: i guess that's what i will have to do if no more easier approach is available. yes the answer of the post is really good giving a background on the problem. And also lots of libraries.Thanks alot!